# comparing two folders for difference

Tags: c#, .net, console

Hi i'm currently working on a c# console app that will compare two folders for difference file content

```
Folder1
  folder A
  folder B
  folder C

Folder 2
  folder A
  folder B
  folder C
```

The Concept of the project is every 1 hr it will check if folders 1 and 2 are the same if not it will look the subfolders names which has different.
is there any way to compare for difference of these folders

i have these on my code but don't know whats next

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path1= @"C:\Users\nx011116\Documents\test folder\server";
            string path2 = @"C:\Users\nx011116\Documents\test folder\sharedfolder";

            DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(path1);
            DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(path2);

            IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        }
```

i need to make sure that both folder is identically same including the log file inside the subfolder

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried ?

Comment: i updated my question, i need to compare not only the folders but also the file within the subfolders and which sub folder has the dault of not beaing same

Comment: for more details :You can write your own logic according to that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-compare-the-contents-of-two-folders-linq

Comment: Do you mean contains files with the same file names or do you want to include file contents as well?

Comment: i mean the comparing of folders if they have the same files

Comment: May I ask why you want to run this comparison? I ask because if the difference is going to be fed into a program or piece of code that copies over the missing files from one location to the other, a simple call to ROBOCOPY to do it all in one go would be better.

Comment: that comparison is for notification. the file from folder 2 is from folder 1  it being copied by other program , now this program is to ensure if the program is copying if it is not it will email,thats why i need to compair if it is exactly the same. this two folder need to ensure that it is the same

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<string> GetDiffOfSubfolders(string source, string dest)
{
    DirectoryInfo sourceDir = new DirectoryInfo(source);

    DirectoryInfo destinationDir = new DirectoryInfo(dest);

    var subDirsSrc = sourceDir.GetDirectories();
    var subDirsDesc = destinationDir.GetDirectories();
    var subDirsDescFolderNames = subDirsDesc.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

    List<string> notMatchedSubFolders = new List<string>();

    foreach (var folder in subDirsSrc)
    {
        if (subDirsDescFolderNames.Contains(folder.Name))
        {
            DirectoryInfo sourceSubDir = new DirectoryInfo(folder.FullName);
            var list1 = sourceSubDir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x.FullName));

            string destinationSubFolderName = subDirsDesc.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == folder.Name).FullName;
            DirectoryInfo destSubDir = new DirectoryInfo(destinationSubFolderName);
            var list2 = destSubDir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x.FullName));

            var diff = list1.Except(list2);

            if (diff.Any())
            {
                notMatchedSubFolders.Add(folder.FullName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            notMatchedSubFolders.Add(folder.FullName);
        }
    }

    return notMatchedSubFolders;
}
```

Comment: is there a way doing this with traditional c#, not using lamda?

Comment: I update the answer. if you want use without lamda, then use for loops for each one. Go line by line carefully and ask if you are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get all directories name.

 string [] subdirectoryEntries1 = Directory.GetDirectories("folder1path");
 string [] subdirectoryEntries2 = Directory.GetDirectories("folder1path");

Get all files name
  foreach(string dir in subdirectoryEntries1)
  {
     string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
     foreach(string file in fileEntries )
     {
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
     }
  }

now you can use LINQ

var diff1= subdirectoryEntries1.Except(subdirectoryEntries2)
var diff2= subdirectoryEntries2.Except(subdirectoryEntries1)
```

Comment: how can i add condition if it is identical?

Comment: you can use logic for that in next line.

Comment: i think this only compares the subfolders not including the files inside the subfolders

Comment: what i mean in my question is the file inside is included

Comment: you need to use another function for it. m updating answer

Comment: sorry but seems like stupid question, now that i can compare the contents of the subfolders how can i know which sub folder dont have the same files in it

Comment: You have to use GetFiles and compare those lists as well.

Comment: now you are increasing question. and i think you are assigning a task